# Не могу использовать pyttsx3 на реальном хостинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pyttsx3

У меня есть код, который приветствует пользователя на странице с помощью модуля pyttsx3. На localhost работает очень хорошо, т.к библиотека `TTS` напрямую подключается к звуковому оборудованию, а на реальном хостинге нет.

Главный вопрос:

**как я могу обработать сгенерированный звук и отправить его через Интернет в браузер?**

`python:`

```
@app.route('/speech', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def say_txt():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say("Hello John, how can I help you")
    engine.runAndWait()
    return render_template('speech.html', engine=engine)
```

`speech.html:`

```
<h4 class="white-text">
  {{ engine }}
</h4>
```

`engine` переменная просто показывает адрес памяти. Я ее добавил для общего понимания.